# How to set File Path in Netbeans ide

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a desktop application in which I am using Jasper report design file **(jrxml**).
I put the jrxml file in the same folder where I have my java code.
As the file path I used

```
FileInputStream fl = new FileInputStream("D:\\Sandeep MIS project21.02.2014\\Workspace for Hording\\HordingDept\\src\\HordingDept\\report2.jrxml");
```

But instead of this I want a simple

```
File file=new File("report2.jrxml");
```

My src folder is **HordingDept**.
But using the simple path Netbeans shows an eror "**file not found**".
What should I do? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
File file=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\HordingDept\\report2.jrxml");
```

Comment: yeah its work but i have to create the jar file of my project and run on another system then this dont work...please give me another suggestion

Comment: @Sandy your src folder is not included in jar. Thus file not found. Keep the file which directory is available in jar or create a resourece dir and include this dir in jar.

Comment: ..tell me please how to create resource dir and include this dir in jar